# Karma ng-html2js preprocessor not generating modules

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to debug how my karma setup is not preprocessing my directive templates.

I hoped that by setting `moduleName: foo` I could easily grab the module in Chrome debug console and see what's up, but trying `angular.module('foo')` in the debug returns a `no module found` error leading me to believe the issue is somewhere else.

I also tried changing the html preprocessor to some nonsense string hoping that karma would throw an error, but it does not. This leads me to think that the issue may be with not having the correct path for my templates, but if I change that path to something else, it does throw an error `no files match this path`.

Are there any debug options/approaches that I'm missing? Is there a way to log what goes in/comes out of ng-html2js?

Here is my `karma.conf.js`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    plugins: [
      // these plugins will be require() by Karma
      'ng-html2js',
      'jasmine',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      APPLICATION_SPEC,
      '../app/assets/javascripts/image-crop.js',
      '../app/assets/javascripts/angular/**/*.js',
      '../spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.js',
      "../public/templates/**/*.html"
    ],
    exclude: [
      './app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
    ],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'public/templates',
      moduleName: 'foo',
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,


    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any debug options/approaches that I'm missing? Is there a
>   way to log what goes in/comes out of ng-html2js?

Yes; `karma start --log-level debug` will display `DEBUG [preprocessor.html2js]` entries. However you'll only get those entries if the `files` paths and the `preprocessors` pattern are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This appeared to be an issue with pathing because when I added the base path `basePath: '../'` to my karma config and adjusted my `files:` paths, the preprocessor worked correctly.